# Can't see other email accounts in Outlook 365 after upgrading SSD

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I just cloned my Thinkpad's SSD from a 256gb one to a 512GB one using Marcium Reflect and although everything else seems to work fine, Outlook 365 doesn't show the column (*that normally appears on the left side in the default view*) that shows things like:

1. list of all my inboxes
2. list of all my folders, e.g., sent and spam folders
3. list of all my drafts

Because that column isn't there, I can only see the emails from one of my accounts (which also happens to be my only Microsoft Exchange email account). I can't change which account is viewable.

I know I'm still signed into my other email addresses because I can see a list of my 11 email accounts when I go to File → Info → Account settings →  Account Settings and I can still send email from those email accounts.
I tried the registry edit for Outlook Express, but Outlook 365 doesn't seem to have that registry value. Besides, this is a personal machine managed only by me.
And yes, I tried reinstalling Office 365 (this is on Windows 10)

[image: Here's a screenshot]

Comment: Are you talking about File > Account settings > Account Settings > email section ?

Comment: No I'm talking about the list of email accounts on the left side in the regular view

Comment: How many accounts do you expect it to show you there ? How many accounts does it show in the section I asked above ? Are you talking about added mailboxes ? Put up a screenshot for us to see

Comment: @pun screenshot added. Sorry - I have a suitable image editor so I had to download GIMP

Comment: Your screenshot nearly blinded me :D

Comment: Why was my screenshot changed?

Comment: Because there was nothing to show in your screenshot except for a giant black patch and some more black patch. This screenshot is showing the same thing as your problem is

Comment: Not sure what your clone of the hard drive has anything to do with your issue... other than a timing issue.  Have you looked at this? https://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/09/outlook-2013-empty-folder-pane-issue-heres-fix/

Comment: @Sun the problem only happens when I boot from my cloned hard drive. Booting from the old drive doesn't have this problem. 
Considering that both drives should be theoretically identical (except for the additional space), it is surprising that it would behave differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution:

Select View on the menu bar.

In the ribbon, select folder pane drop down

Select Normal.

The folders will be restored.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried messing with this for an hour or so then gave up and used Thunderbird for a month lol

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with an update in November 2017.  The solution for me was quite simple:

1. Expand Outlook to full screen
2. Move the cursor to the extreme left hand side until it shows the icon for changing column widths (as in Excel)
3. Left click while the icon is showing and drag it to the right